# capturar fórmula excel com php

Tags: php, microsoft-excel

Preciso capturar a fórmula que está por tras da geração dos dados de um excel com php, porém em todas as minhas importações só consegui capturar o valor do campo, como proceder?

Comment: Seu sistema recebe um upload de uma planilha ou csv?